# unable to read values into global array variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope, global-variables

I am working on a javascript code that looks like the following. I am only showing the basic skeleton of the code first.

```
var array = [];

function mainFun()
{
     A();
}
function A()
{
    //some code
    B();
    //code to print all values in "array"
}

function B()
{
    C();
}

function C()
{
     //some code
     //push elements one by one in "array"
     for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
     {
           array.push(i); //something on these lines
     }
}
```

I know this code seems bizarre but this is exactly the situation I am working on. Thanks to Javascript's function level scoping (as against the regular block-level scoping), I am unable to access and print all the elements in `A()` that have been pushed in the array in `C()`. So how can I make my array variable work like a true global variable that has knowledge of what elements were pushed into it?

Ok, here is my original source code (I don't know how the dummy code worked though!)

```
var allLinks = {}; //set of all internal and external links
var Queued = [];
var crawlingURL;
var Crawled = [];
var xmlHttp = null, originURL, maxHops = 0, currentHop = 0;

function changeText(){
    var tabID, sourceURL;
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        console.log(tabs[0].url);
        document.getElementById('URL').innerHTML="URL of Current Page : "+tabs[0].url;
        tabID = tabs[0].id;
        sourceURL = tabs[0].url;

        Queued.push(sourceURL); //push the origin link the Queued array to begin crawling
        beginCrawl(sourceURL);
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    changeText();
});

function beginCrawl(url)
{
    originURL = url;
    maxHops = 2;
    currentHop = 1;
    var queueIndex = 0;
    //httpGet(originURL);
    while(queueIndex<1) //(currentHop <= maxHops)
    {
        crawlingURL = Queued[queueIndex];
        //allPages[crawlingURL] = {url:url, state:"crawling", level:0, host:startingHost};
        httpGet(crawlingURL);
        Crawled.push(crawlingURL);
        queueIndex++;

        for(var j = 0; j < Queued.length; j++)
        {
            console.log(j+". "+Queued[j]+"\n");
        }
    }
}
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
}

function ProcessRequest()
{
    if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) // xmlHTTP success
    {           
            var container = document.createElement("p");
            container.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
            var anchors = container.getElementsByTagName("a");
            var list = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) 
            {
                var href = anchors[i].href;
                var exists = 0;

                // to check for duplicate entries in the list
                    for(var j = 0; j < Queued.length; j++)  // remove duplicates
                        if(Queued[j] == href)
                            exists = 1;
                    if (exists == 0)
                    {
                        Queued.push(href);
                        document.getElementById('printORGLinks').innerHTML += href + "<br />";
                    }
            }
        }
}
```

I am unable to get print the values in my Queued Array ! (As you may understand, this is a preliminary code for a web crawler of some sort. I need to get the list of all URLs pushed into the Queued array).

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Your `array` variable is global, so you can access it anywhere.

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: Are you not invoking `mainFun()` Otherwise it should just work fine...

Comment: Maybe you've a `var array` inside your `A` function that obfuscates the global `array` variable?

Comment: Also at what point are you calling `mainFun()`?

Comment: It works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/qsshM/

Comment: [Yup](http://jsfiddle.net/uyyaD/1/).

Comment: Any chance that the part that pushes new values to the array is inside an AJAX call?

Comment: Hi everyone, I am sorry I do not know how the previous code was working. But I have made an Edit now and added the original source for reference, which does not work the way it should. I do not get a list of all URLs in my Queued array and that is where the problem lies.

Comment: Yup, it's an AJAX issue. You're trying to access the array before `httpGet(crawlingURL);` has completed.

Comment: @Andy: I don't get it, when I make the XMLHTTP request using httpGet(), isn't the AJAX call already done with by the time I get to the line where I need to access the values?

Comment: No, the call to httpGet() returns immediately without the browser even starting the ajax call. It merely tells the browser to schedule a HTTP request when it has free CPU time and the browser doesn't have free CPU time while js is running. Only after js has completed running and passes over execution to the browser does the browser notice that it has to make an HTTP request. When the request is done several seconds later the browser calls the ProcessRequest callback. That's the whole point of callbacks - a mechanism for you to tell the browser what to execute after some asynchronous event.

Comment: That's great information. Can anyone tell me how I can make sure that the AJAX call completes and executes ProcessRequest before I do other processing and check the array contents!?!

Answer (score 0):

This works as you've entered it - fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/LmFqq/1/

Output

```
some code executing in A()
some code executing in B()
adding elements in C()
printing in A()
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Code

```
var array = [];
var el = document.getElementById('output');
mainFun();

function log(msg) {
    el.innerHTML += msg + "<br />";
}

function mainFun()
{
     A();
}

function A()
{
    log("some code executing in A()");
    B();

    log("printing in A()");
    log(JSON.stringify(array));
}

function B()
{
    log("some code executing in B()");
    C();
}

function C()
{
    log("adding elements in C()");
     for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
     {
           array.push(i); //something on these lines
     }
}
```

Comment: "You don't have a problem" isn't an answer.